# Passport PKCE auth, redirect after registration with access code

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I have an auth/resource server and a single-page application (SPA) in different containers. They are running on two different web servers. All login and registration happens in the auth/resource server application. The thing is, I want to redirect end-users to the SPA frontend (e.g., dashboard) with an access code right after registration. However, for the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE), I use a public client. So, after I create the user, when I try to generate an access token with Laravel/Passport's HasApiToken Trait createToken method, it returns an error as expected because there is no personal/private client.

For login, I follow the PKCE concept, and everything works fine. But the registration flow goes like this: the end-user selects the pricing tier and is redirected to the authentication server registration flow with parameters such as selected tier, scope, etc. After all registration and payment steps are done, I want to redirect the users to the dashboard template on the frontend app with an access token so the user can start using the application.

My problem is that I cannot and actually don't know how to create an access code for a user when there is no personal/private client. Of course, at the authentication/backend service in the controller, I can send subsequent requests to the Passport/OAuth endpoints, and it would generate. But I don't think that would be the best practice. An app sending requests to itself.

Can anyone tell me how can I authenticate my frontend application which is running on different server with a different domain than auth server application? All I am thinking is if I can redirect the user with access token to the frontend application, then all would work. If this is wrong approach, please enlighten me on this. Basically what I am trying to create is SSO concept with a Laravel/Passport without SAML. So multiple applications can be authenticated authorized on that Laravel/Passport application. For login and all others it is alright, but registration is tricky.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with the PKCE method as you stated since you are starting the authentication from the auth side. If it were me, I would make the user create an account prior to purchase to confirm who they are via email authentication, have them log in after authentication and the proceed to purchase.

Comment: @RobDiablo Thanks for the suggestion. I am very new in OAuth PKCE concept, I posted my situation here to get some ideas for the best practice. You made me sure your way of handling sounds the most proper way. Well until I setup the email verification, I figured another way that is; Auth server registers user and redirects to a trigger endpoint on the frontend that forces frontend to login/start authentication and already user authenticated at the auth server so it just a quick redirects. Seems creepy but works. Thanks again